# Integral equals sum for $L^2$ function with compact-support transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

> Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be such that $\hat{f}$ is supported on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Show that $$\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|^2dx=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty|f(n)|^2$$

I know that $f$ must be continuous and going to $0$ at $\pm\infty$. The term on the left is just $\|f\|_2^2$. How can we relate that to the sum on the right?

Comment: Check the fourier series of a function. See [Parseval's identity](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_identity).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Here there's no $\hat{f}$, only $f$.

Comment: @PJMiller: And what is the Fourier transform of $\hat{f}$?

Comment: @NateEldredge It is $g(y)=\int_\mathbb{R}\hat{f}(x)e^{-ixy}dx=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\hat{f}(x)e^{-ixy}dx$. How does that help?

Comment: @pjmiller: compare with the Fourier inversion formula.

Comment: @NateEldredge Got it.. I was fooled because I was focusing on the negative sign in the sum. But since $n$ runs from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, I can consider $n$ instead of $-n$ and use the Fourier inversion formula. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can apply Parseval's identity on $\hat{f}$:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty|c_n|^2=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi|\hat{f}(x)|^2dx,$$ where $$c_n=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \hat{f}(x)e^{-inx}dx.$$ Using the Fourier inversion formula, the left-hand side is $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |f(-n)|^2$, which is the same as $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |f(n)|^2$.

Applying Plancherel's formula on the right-hand side yields the desired equality.